# System.DayOfWeek enum - Entity errors on save with KnownType issues; DevForce 2012

Tags: c#, dayofweek, devforce, known-types

DevForce 2012 7.2.2, EF 5, Silverlight, C#, VS2012

Entity property of type `System.DayOfWeek`, erroring (full error messages below) that it needs to be added to the list of known types when trying to update/save a change of this property to a different value. 
Seems odd, considering it's a System Enumerable, and it's listed as a specific example that can be used in the DevForce documentation (http://drc.ideablade.com/devforce-2012/bin/view/Documentation/enum-types)

So I created an `IKnownTypeProvider` and added `DayOfWeek` as an entry:

```
public class LwKnownTypeProvider : IKnownTypeProvider
{
    public IEnumerable<Type> AddKnownTypes()
    {
        var list = new Type[]
                       {
                           typeof (DayOfWeek)
                       };
        return list;
    }
}
```

For fun, I also tried being a bit more specific, in case there was somewhere the tools were getting confused (replace `DayOfWeek` with `System.DayOfWeek` throughout), but this yielded the same results.

Things I've checked:

- Is the `IKnownTypeProvider` being found? Breakpoints successfully being hit
- Is it on both the SL & Server side? Yes, the class definition file is in both projects. Yes, it's listed in collection of known types (provided by `var lstKnownTypes = IdeaBlade.EntityModel.KnownTypeHelper.GetServiceKnownTypes(null);`)

Inherited code, so maybe I'm overlooking something, but I'm not seeing it.

Error saving changes prior to adding the IKnownTypeProvider:

> Type 'System.DayOfWeek' with data contract name DayOfWeek:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2005/07/system' is not
>   expected. Add any types not known statically to the list of known
>   types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute or by adding them
>   to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer

Error after adding the `IKnownTypeProvider` listed above:

> The formatter thew an exception while trying to deserialize the
>   message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter
>   ideablade.com/EntityModel:workState. The InnerException message was
>   'Element 'ideablade.com/EntityModel:OriginalValue' contains data from
>   a type that maps to the name
>   'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2005/07/System:DayOfWeek'. The
>   deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name.
>   Consider using a DataContractResolver or add the type corresponding to
>   'DayOfWeek' to the list of known types - for example, by adding the
>   KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding it to the list of known
>   types pased to DataContractSerializer.'. Please see InnerException for
>   more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug with how the enum types are handled during an update when these changed properties are part of the original values passed to the server.  The workaround for now is to implement your IKnownTypeProvider on **both** client and server.

Comment: I revisited where I had implemented the IKnownTypeProvider at, as it was located within a project outside of the database model. It was available on both the client and server side in that shared resource, but it was still causing the issue. Moving the declarations into the model project instead, this has happily resolved itself. Must have been a long day yesterday, as I'm not sure why it didn't go there to begin with. Thanks!